# Manga where the MC is a saint and transported to another world with another girl but is cast aside and almost killed

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, magical-transportation

The protagonist of the story is transported to another world, but another girl, (who I'll name B) who always causes trouble for the MC ends up following her to wreak more havoc in her life. When summoned, B can see the titles and names of those around them, but the main character cannot, so B takes advantage of the situation and proclaims she is the saint. The MC is cast aside from everything and, to ensure her lies don't get discovered, she makes sure that only she could use healing magic, and when the MC said she used it, she is thrown out of the castle, whereupon she heads to a monastery near the border where the war is being held. The carriage that she was in was attacked, she used the healing powers to stun the men attacking, which caused the guard to call her evil, stab her, and take some of her hair back as proof. The MC heals herself and gets ready to travel in the woods, when she meets an old man asking if she is OK.

The mangas is fairly new and only has one chapter out so far, but I can’t find it in my history or by looking it up.

Comment: I'm guessing that the "FL" is meant to be the "Main Character" through some alchemy of word transubstantiation. I'm guessing you read this online? Did it look like it was a scanlation? What sites do you read on? Just to confirm, the actual main character was a girl?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Seijo no Hazu ga, Douyara Nottoraremashita](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/seijo-no-hazu-ga-douyara-nottoraremashita)* or *I Was Summoned to Be the Saint, but I Was Robbed of the Position, Apparently*, based on [a web novel of the same name](https://ncode.syosetu.com/n0469ft/).

> Anise suddenly gets a message on her phone one day asking whether she'd be willing to lend her their aid. As if responding to her thoughts, it chooses for her and she finds herself suddenly summoned into the world of an otome game. While Hime is dumbfounded at her situation, Hime, the girl who is summoned with her declares, "I'm the saint!" As a result, Anise is treated as useless and driven out. If things were to continue to go on like this, then the general of the neighboring country will die, Hime, as the saint, will take over, and a tragic ending will be met. To avoid that and take her life into her own hands, Anise resolves to save the general, change the scenario, and just settle down somewhere, or that was what she planned, however...

Found by searching for *isekai manga saint*, which brought me to [anime-planet's isekai section](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tags/summoned-into-another-world), and eventually [a search for isekai manga with the word "saint" in their title](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/all?name=saint&include_tags=1025). There were just a handful, so I clicked into each one.